# How to copy cells to new location while removing blanks?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am looking for a formula that reads one row of 5 cells, and fills the new row with the contents of the original row, but with the non-numeric cells removed and the rest shifted to the left:

```
Original

     *P*     *Q*     *R*     *S*     *T*
*23*          8       3               2
```

(Note: The "blank" cells aren't actually blank, the only way I can get them to read correctly in a formula is if I reference them as "". I am guessing this is because `P23:T23` are also references to other cells, instead of direct numbers.)

```
Result

     *B*     *C*     *D*     *E*     *F*
*3*   8       3       2
```

I am looking for the formula to be executed in cell B3. I thought this would work:

```
=FILTER(P23:T23,NOT(ISBLANK(P23:T23)))
```

but, it didn't get rid of the blank cells, probably because Google Sheets doesn't think `P23 & S23` are blank. Any ideas?

Edit: Here's a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14M6XggpIUXNdZ5ihQ7ipim44wsn4u-ywMZCG4kYMlQY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Link added to post

Comment: this strikes me as very likely an x-y problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(JOIN(",", IF(ISNUMBER(P23:T23*1), P23:T23, )), ","))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=FILTER(P23:T23, ISNUMBER(P23:T23))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!